# React-transition-group. Animation not working

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group

I am new to React. I want my rectangle to fade in and out when the button is clicked. I use  for this. I do everything according to the documentation.
Here is my component code:

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {CSSTransition} from "react-transition-group";

const Test = () => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
    const nodeRef = useRef(null);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>ACTION</button>
            <CSSTransition
                in={visible}
                nodeRef={nodeRef}
                timeout={500}
                classNames="alert"
                mountOnEnter
                unmountOnExit
            >
                <div className="square"/>
            </CSSTransition>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

And my css code:

```
.square {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.alert-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
.alert-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
.alert-exit {
    opacity: 1;
}
.alert-exit-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
```

From what I see on the screen a red square, I conclude that my component sees the css file.
I also understand that the  wrapper works because the square disappears and appears when the button is pressed.
But the animation doesn't work and I don't know why.
The css code that describes the animation is taken from the official documentation.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `nodeRef={nodeRef}` from your CSSTransition. So your code should be:

```
<div>
  <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>ACTION</button>
  <CSSTransition
   in={visible}
   timeout={500}
   classNames="alert"
   mountOnEnter
   unmountOnExit
  >
    <div className="square"/>
  </CSSTransition>
</div>
```